# The two spans cannot be aligned on the same line

Tags: html

[image]Dears,

I am making a name card and the codes are below:

I want to align the last two spans "STUDIO ICONIC" and "info@studioiconic.net" on the same line, however it is always appeared that the email span comes after like the picture show.  Is possible to basically adjusted something to achieve that? or is there something i do it wrong?  If possible i don't want to use grip or flexbox...Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body style="border: 2px solid green; width: 500px; height: 270px;">
<div >
    <img src = "../smile1.jpg" 
    style="margin-left: 50px; 
        margin-top: 20px;
        float: left; 
        width: 150px; 
        height: 150px;">
    
    <p style="margin-left: 300px;">
    <B>ODEN QUEST</B>
    <br>
    <span><em>Creative Director</em></span>
    </p> 
    <p style="margin-left: 300px;">
        <span>T +1 408 456 7890</span>
        <br>
        <span>M +1 408 456 8956</span>
        </p>
    <p style="margin-left: 300px;">
    <span>1234 Main Street</span>
    <br>
    <span>Sanita Clara, CA 95126</span>
    </p>
    <br style="clear:both;">
    <span style="margin-left: 65px; display: inline;">STUDIO ICONIC</span>
    <span style="margin-left: 300px; display: inline;">info@studioiconic.net</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using grid and flexbox are going to be easier than using floats, which have been long since deprecated and not recommended.

Comment: @Phix Citation? Who deprecated floats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way for layout is `flex`. About the inline style, it is highly recommended that don't use it. instead, use classes for your styling.

```css
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
}
.image-container{
  margin-left: 50px; 
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 150px; 
  height: 150px;
  border:2px solid gainsboro;
}
.image{
  width:100%;
}
.right-side{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  margin-left:100px;
}

.info{
  display:flex;
}

.s1{
  padding-left: 65px; 
}
.s2{
  margin-left:120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="image" src = "../smile1.jpg" alt="smile face">
  </div>
  <section class="right-side">
    <p>
      <b>ODEN QUEST</b>
      <br>
      <span><em>Creative Director</em></span>
    </p> 
    <p>
       <span>T +1 408 456 7890</span>
       <br>
       <span>M +1 408 456 8956</span>
    </p>
    <p>
      <span>1234 Main Street</span>
      <br>
      <span>Sanita Clara, CA 95126</span>
    </p>
  </section>
</div>
<div class="info">
  <span class="s1">STUDIO ICONIC</span>
  <span class="s2">info@studioiconic.net</span>
</div>
```

For detection only, in the code that you wrote, you should change `display` and `margin-left` of your `span`.(span by default is `display:inline`)

```html
<div >
    <img src = "../smile1.jpg" 
    style="margin-left: 50px; 
        margin-top: 20px;
        float: left; 
        width: 150px; 
        height: 150px;">
    
    <p style="margin-left: 300px;">
    <B>ODEN QUEST</B>
    <br>
    <span><em>Creative Director</em></span>
    </p> 
    <p style="margin-left: 300px;">
        <span>T +1 408 456 7890</span>
        <br>
        <span>M +1 408 456 8956</span>
        </p>
    <p style="margin-left: 300px;">
    <span>1234 Main Street</span>
    <br>
    <span>Sanita Clara, CA 95126</span>
    </p>
    <br style="clear:both;">
    <span style=" margin-left:65px;">STUDIO ICONIC</span>
    <span style="margin-left:110px;">info@studioiconic.net</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Great!  Thanks for your help.  I don't know that before, i mean the margin of the span, i though it always reference with the edge of the body, don't know that it reference with that of other span also....do you know where i can get this info from some official website? By the way, it seems my previous code use fewer lines, why you and many people says it is better to use flex, not this simple codes....Thanks for your help and advice.

Comment: You're welcome. The margin property defines the outermost portion of the box model, creating space around an element. You can read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin or https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/margin/. Less code does not matter. instead, readability and maintenance of code are more important. And also with flexbox, you have more control over elements alignment.
Read these sites:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Typical_Use_Cases_of_Flexbox and https://medium.com/@tu7a1k23/css-why-we-use-flexbox-7ba4d417118b